# cmder passing wrong characters to console

Tags: cygwin, cmder

When I try to edit any file in vim Cmder is pasing wrong characters.

arrow up/down are writing "←OB" or "←OA"

ctrl + a is typing "☺"

I'm using CMDER + cygwin. Any idea how to make it work ?

Answer (score 0):

I cannot comment due to a low reputation but can you post some more details e.g. what version of Cmder and Cygwin are you using? Also if you run the Cygwin outside Cmder, does it work? What kind of keyboard do you have and which keyboard layout do you use?

I had no issues with Cygwin, I created a task like this and it worked. I just put this into "Commands" (my cygwin is installed in the C:\Users\mflop\Apps:

```
C:\Users\mflop\Apps\cygwin\bin\mintty.exe -i /Cygwin-Terminal.ico -
```

If that does not work, go to **Cmder settings -> Keys & Macro -> Keyboard** and try to play a bit with the settings there, especially the part **Seize keys/Send to console**. Some settings there might conflict with your Cygwin version. Also if you run it in the restricted environment (typically corporate setup with no admin rights, firewalls etc.) the Cmder and Cygwin might be affected by that.